# Grabbing google sponsored sites

Tags: python, serpapi

I'm trying to grab a sponsored google site via an api called serpapi on python. But it doesn't seem to grab them. it only displays no ads

[image: Sponsored Link]

This is the code that I use.

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import json, os

params = {
    "api_key": "APIKEY",
    "engine": "google_local",
    "q": "Crypto Buy",
    "location": "Indonesia",
    "google_domain": "google.co.id",
    "gl": "us",
    "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
Sponsored_results = search.get_dict()

if sponsored_results.get("Sponsored", []):
    for ad in results["Sponsored"]:
        print(json.dumps(Sponsored, indent=2))

if sponsored_results.get("shopping_results", []):
    for shopping_ad in results["shopping_results"]:
        print(json.dumps(shopping_ad, indent=2))
else:
    print("no sponsores found.")
```

When I run it, I didn't get any result at all, Is it because the API can't do link searching?

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Please regenerate your API key at: https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key since you leaked your API key and everyone can use it.

Comment: Thank you @DmitriyZub, I forgot to erase the API key

Comment: of course :) Such things happens :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try using this please?

```py
search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

if results.get("ads", []):
    for ad in results["ads"]:
        print(json.dumps(ad, indent=2))
elif results.get("shopping_results", []):
    for shopping_ad in results["shopping_results"]:
        print(json.dumps(shopping_ad, indent=2)).     
else:
    print("no shopping ads found.")
```

Reference link : [Google Ad Results API](https://serpapi.com/google-ads?ref=serpapi.com)

Comment: I've already found the solution, and it's the same as your answer. Thank you!